# Consultant to review project work plan

Tags: work-breakdown-structure, reviews

I am responding to a request for proposal (RFP) that is requiring us to provide a Work Breakdown Structure, a deliverable list with details for each deliverable, and a list of resources by role in each phase with their estimated effort.

I really want to make sure I am doing this correctly, as it's a fairly large part of the evaluation scoring, but I am finding there are varying examples of what should be included.

I would like to create my draft plan and work with a project management consultant who can help me improve it and ensure I am covering everything that is being asked.

My question is, where can I find a person to review this?  I obviously did some googling and the only things I found are huge consultant firms that would be overkill for this relatively small review I need.  Do any of you have any ideas where I would look to hire someone to review this?

Comment: As written, this question really seems to be less about Project Management than it does about HR or staffing issues. Search questions like "where can I find..." are off-topic everywhere on the Stack Exchange network, so unless you can refactor your question it is likely to be closed. http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used any of them for PM recruitment but there are a lot of 'collaborative consumption' sites out there where you can post an opportunity and get bids in for the work from suppliers ([Elance](https://www.elance.com) is one of the most popular). You'll more than likely get bids from individuals or small companies rather than large consultancies.

Stepping back a little I'm slightly concerned, from a PM perspective, that you're pitching for work that you won't be able to adequately project manage. If you don't have the PM skills in-house now and need to get someone else to help win the work how will you actually deliver the project if you do win?